# Issue while opening the file in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to open a file using perl command. When I am passing a variable in between the file path, perl is not able to open the file: (here *$line*)

```
open(FL, "<C:/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/$line/project.txt") or die "Could not open file $!";
```

and If I try to open the file by passing the full path instead of variable **($line)** in the path, Perl is able to open the file successfully:

```
open(FL, "<C:/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/projectName/project.txt") or die "Could not open file $!";
```

Could somebody please guide me how to achieve this. I have a list of projects and I cannnot pass name of every project manually but I need to achieve this by passing **projectName**s as the variables **$line**.

NOTE: All the ***$line*** variables are my ***projectName***s.

Comment: Use three-argument open: `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";`. You can then of course say `open my $fh, '<', "/path/$line/etc"`

Comment: are you trying to automatically read the name from path by using $line? Or are you declaring an array of names and passing each of them to a scalar?

Comment: `my $file = "C:/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/$line/project.txt";
open($in, "<", $file) or die "blah blah...!\n";`

Comment: Try this:    open(FL, "<C:/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/"@{[$line]}"/project.txt") or die "Could not open file $!";

Comment: `$line = qutoemeta($line); open (..` try this one

Comment: @Gerhard, yes I put all the project names in one file and after reading, generating an array and then proceeding further.

Comment: @zdim and ssr1012  I tried both the ways already.

Comment: @VinayVerma  OK, you found what it was and that is great. But I'd like to emphasize -- the three argument open is just better to use, for a number of reasons. In general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you reading your project names from another file? If so, did you remember to remove `\n` at the end (using `chomp $line` or similar)?

Comment: Yes, I used chomp. still not getting output as expected. I while calling $line, I can am able to work on first project in the list successfully but for all the other projects it is still failing.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your `$line` having some special character it won't allow, so we shopuld escape the character, use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
$line = qutoemeta($line); 
open  my $fh, "<" ,$line or die "Error opening $!";
```

You will fix the error by `$!`. Already you have added it in your code. 
Please follow what it is saying.

Comment: Yes, It was only saying that the file cannot be opened. well, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44302114/7745725 solution worked for me :-)
Thanks!